# If we select a rearrangement of AABBCCDDEE at random, what is the probability that the two A’s will appear together?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I decided to solve this by considering AA as one letter. In that case we have 9!/(2!)^4 permutations. The total permutations would be 10!/(2!)^5. Dividing gets you 1/5, but that just doesn't seem like it can possibly be true. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Edit: Would you have to make accommodations for distinction between same letters? Like, $A_1A_2 vs A_2A_1$?

Comment: Why doesn't it seem like it can possibly be true?

Comment: @ModdedBear There are 10 letters, there are so many possibilities. How can the chance of AA be 1/5? Is it just a case of being a beginner to the topic and not having a good grasp of probabilities?

Comment: ^Human intuition for probability is generally terrible

Comment: @Bob: One _definitely not rigorous_ way of calibrating the intuition would be to imagine you're one of the two As. What is the probablity that the other one is next to you? There are _two_ positions that are your neighbors and _ten_ positions the other A could end up in, for a probability of 2/10=1/5. (This is very approximate -- it ignores the fact that you might be at the end of the line and have only one neighboring position, and also ignores the fact that the other A can't be at _your_ position so has only 9 positions to choose from. But even se, you see 1/5 is in the right ballpark ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of looking at it: the other letters being irrelevant to the question, there are two A's and $8$ non-A's.   Out of the $10$ positions you choose two for the A's: there are ${10 \choose 2} = 45$ equally likely ways of doing that.  The non-A's go in the other eight positions, we don't care how.  Of those $45$ possible positions for the A's, $9$ have the two A's together.  So the probability of the two A's being together is $9/45 = 1/5$.

Answer (score 0):

You have a total of $\frac{10!}{2!^5}$ rearrangements, true. If you 'fix' AA in the first two slots, you have $\frac{8!}{2!^4}$. You have in total 9 positions for AA.

Comment: I actually thought about that first. I decided there were 9 options for where AA could go, but then was stuck figuring the total number of possibilities, and so was unable to figure out the probability.

Comment: I just count the total number of allocations and those that you need and make sure there's no overcounting (none in our case because every time the AA positions aer unique)